# Automatic script running on a column being filled in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 2 columns say Column A and Column B in a Google spreadsheet. I have a function(spreadsheet script) which on running opens a panel (used to accept some values). I want to make the process automatic i.e. when row 1 of column A and row 1 of column B are filled the script for the panel should run and display the panel automatically, again when row 2 to column A and row 2 of column B are filled, the script should rerun. I would like to mention that the panel closes after the value is accepted, so i am needing to run the script again and again.

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var col   = activecell.getColumn();
  var row   = activecell.getRow();

 if (col == 1 || col == 2) { // only runs when col A or B is edited
   // only runs if the columns are both not empty
   if(sheet.getRange(row, 1).getValue() != "" && sheet.getRange(row, 2).getValue() != "") {
     CALL YOUR FUNCTION TO OPENS THE PANNEL
   }
 }
}
```